# python parsing extract text from html

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made a parsing code like below

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from pprint import pprint
import requests

html = requests.get('http://a2-m.etoosanswer.co.kr/board/notice/main.do')
soup = bs(html.text, 'html.parser')
data4 = soup.findAll('strong', {'class': 'tit'})

print(data4)
```

and the result of this is

```
[<strong class="tit">이투스앤써 [N수생전용] 4월 단과시간표 </strong>, <strong class="tit">[공지] 2021학 
년도 대입일정안내</strong>, <strong class="tit">이투스앤써 목동점 4월 1주차 주간식단표</strong>, <strong 
class="tit">[목동앤써] 코로나 19로 인한 '개학연기'에 따른 고3 대응 매뉴얼</strong>, <strong class="tit"> 
이투스앤써 '실시간 채팅상담' 서비스 오픈!</strong>, <strong class="tit">[이투스앤써] 신종 코로나 바이러스 
감염증 예방을 위한 학원 안전 조치 및 예방 수칙 안내</strong>, <strong class="tit">[이투스앤써] 2021학년도 
6월 평가원 모의고사 취소 안내</strong>, <strong class="tit">재수정규 4월 시작반 설명회 [1부] 영상 
</strong>, <strong class="tit">재수정규 4월 시작반 설명회 [3부] 영상</strong>, <strong class="tit">[입시 
컨설팅] 수시/정시 입시 포트폴리오 수행평가를 위한 자소서 완성</strong>, <strong class="tit">이투스앤써 [N수 
생전용] 4월 단과시간표 </strong>]
```

like this.. i want just texts so i add .text command next to data4 = soup.findAll('strong', {'class': 'tit'}) and i got errors.. am i missing something??

Comment: _and the result of this is_ Alright, what's wrong with that? Do you understand what the output is? _and i got errors_ What errors?

Comment: Like i said below the result... i just wanted texts from that results so i put .text next to data4 = soup.findAll('strong', {'class': 'tit'}) and i got errors

Comment: Pardon? How does that address what I wrote in my comment? Again, please provide the entire error message(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return type of `data4` is a list of tags not a tag (bs4.element.Tag) you want.

You need to loop through `data4` in order to get the text you want.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from pprint import pprint
import requests

html = requests.get('http://a2-m.etoosanswer.co.kr/board/notice/main.do')
soup = bs(html.text, 'html.parser')
data4 = soup.findAll('strong', {'class': 'tit'})

for data in data4:
    print(data.text)
```

Output:

```
이투스앤써 [N수생전용] 4월 단과시간표 
[공지] 2021학년도 대입일정안내
...
```